# How to get all indexes from database in ravenDB?

Tags: ravendb

Since i HATE the fact that i have to run VM with IE in order to connect to ravendb web (made with horrible silverlight) i'm loking to use ravendb's http API. So far, only conclusion is that it's docs is horrible and i can't find some options.

Right now, i would need to get the list of index-es. in certain database. However, i can't find that as an option in official docs. http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/http-api

Does that option exist and how to get that list?

Comment: why are you running a Virutal Machine (and with Internet Explorer) to have RavenDb running? Are you doing development on a non-windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint for index list:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/indexes/?start=0&pageSize=256
```

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't get what i needed. ..."Indexes": {
        "Tag": "NotAnalyzed"
      },...

Comment: It returns literally the entire definition of every index, what information is missing that you need? [example](http://i.imgur.com/Cn77rEO.png)